# Why does the variable output "None"

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I am trying to help my friend make a guessing project, but for some reason, the guess variable is NoneType. Can you help me and my friend?

NOTE: I have replaced input() with "hi" for technical reasons.

```py
answer = "whatthing" #Change this to the answer
still_guessing = True
attempts = 1

guess = 'hi'
while still_guessing and attempts < 3:
  print(f'{guess}')
  if guess == answer.lower():
   print('Correct answer!')
   final_score = (3 - attempts)
   still_guessing = False
  else:
    guess = print('Sorry wrong answer. Try again.\n')
    print(f'Tries: {attempts}\n')
    print(f'You have {3 - attempts} left.\n')
    attempts += 1

  if attempts == 3:
    print('You coudn\'t find the answer in three tries, u suck!\n')
    print ('The correct answer is ' + answer)
```

Comment: Because *you assign `None` to it* when you do `guess = print('Sorry wrong answer. Try again.\n')` because `print` returns `None`.

Answer (score 5):

```
guess = print('Sorry wrong answer. Try again.\n')
```

The return value of `print` is `None`.

Take a look at the [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function to get a value from the user.